# How to display visibility status in frontend

Tags: laravel-9

I have created a project in laravel, i have set in blog module that one can be able to switch a post public or private, at the moment when i view the data i see 1 for public and 0 for private, but i need it in to display a word public or private, any help`

```
@foreach($blogs as $row)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                            <td><img src="{{asset('uploads/'.$row->photo)}}" alt="" class="imageSize"></td>
                            <td>{{$row->title}}</td>
                            <td>{!!$row->details!!}</td>
                            <td>
                                @if($row->visibility ==1 ? "Public" : "Private")@endif
                                {{$row->visibility}}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{route('admin_blog_edit',$row->id)}}"  class="btn btn_primary uppercase">Edit</a>
                                <a href="{{route('admin_blog_delete',$row->id)}}" class="btn btn_danger uppercase" onClick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ternary operator` we can do it simply

```
{{ $row->visibility == 1 ? 'public' : 'private' }}
```

The output will be `public` if visibility is `1` and `private` if visibility is `0`.

Answer (score -1):

You're mixing if-clause and ternary here:

```
@if($row->visibility ==1 ? "Public" : "Private")@endif
```

Use either:

```
@if($row->visibility == 1)
Public
@else
Private
@endif
```

or

```
{{ $row->visibility == 1 ? "Public" : "Private" }}
```